# Facing problems with include schemalocation in wsdl using spring boot

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot, wsdl

currently I am working with Spring Boot + SOAP application. Our client has provided one wsdl file and group of xsds which I need to host. My wsdl file contains some schema includes like below.

`<include schemaLocation="ABC-1.0.xsd"/>
<include schemaLocation="XYZ-1.0.xsd"/>`

I am able to publish the wsdl and when I try to test it using soap ui, its causing below exception.

`Error loading [http://localhost:8080/ws/ABC-1.0.xsd]:
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected end of file after null`

Can someone please help me with this. I was totally blank at this point, even after searching couple of articles in google too.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

you have your wsdl somewhere in resources folder right?
So you have to add those xsds there too and use relative path in wsdl.

so when you have something like this:

`resources
--wsdl
----my.wsdl
--xsd
----abc-1.0.xsd`

inside your wsdl you should have relative path like `<include schemaLocation="../xsd/abc-1.0.xsd"/>`

Comment: Both wsdl and schema files are in same location and I am able to generate proxy clases also using Jax-b without fail. so I  guess the problem is some thing else, not with the location...

Comment: so in what framework do you have your soap implementation? Maybe you can provide some code how did you created the endpoint and how did you configured it.